# Can I block settings via Screen Time on iOS 16?

Tags: iphone, ios, screen-time

I would like to block settings or at least sections of settings. For example, the app Reddit has a setting that allows you to filter NSFW content.

Comment: Device?  OS and version?  What settings would you like to “block”?  Can you clarify how Reddit compares?  Blocking NSFW content isn’t the same as blocking settings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, Screen Time cannot be used to block specific parts of apps or settings. You can only block apps overall.

Comment: I see. Sorry, I meant settings in iOS under Reddit's section.

Comment: @imagineerThis I see - I have revised my answer but I don't think the location of the toggle changes anything

Comment: Understood. Thank you.